# Solve the inequality and show solution sets on the real line

Tags: inequality

$$-\frac{x+5}{2} \le \frac {12+3x}{4}$$

I always have issues with problems like this. I chose to ignore the negative sign at the beginning and got the answer. Is that a good method? When solving this inequality what is the best method for no mistakes?

My answer/ method: 
$$-(2)(12+3x) \le (4)(x+5)$$
$$-24-6x \le 4x+20$$
$$-24-20 \le 4x+6x$$
$$-44\le10x$$
$$-\frac{44}{10}\le x$$
$$-\frac{22}{5} \le x$$
$$\left(\infty,-\frac{22}{5}\right]$$

Comment: One added note:  Your answer could aslo be expressed as all  $x \geq -\frac{22}{5}$  which gives us the solutions set $x\in \left[-\frac{22}{5},\infty\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\frac{x+5}{2} \le \frac {12+3x}{4}$$

Multiply $4$ both sides:

$$-2(x+5) \le 12+3x$$

$$-2x-10 \le 12 +3x$$

$$-22 \le 5x$$
 $$x \geq \frac{-22}{5}$$

Your mistakes:

$-2(12+3x)=-24-6x$ rather than $-24+6x$. If this is just a typo, the next line is fine.

After this mistake, surprisingly in the next line, you corrected yourself.

$$x \ge -\frac{22}{5} \iff x \in [\frac{-22}{5},\infty)$$

Comment: Thank you @Siong my mistake(typo)

Answer (score 1):

multiplying by $12$ we obtain
$$-6(x+5)\le 3(12+3x)$$ multiplying out we get
$$-6x-30\le 36+9x$$
thus we have
$$-66\le 15x$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You have one mistake here may be typo -

$$-24+6x \le 4x+20$$

Its,  $$-24-6x \le 4x+20$$

$$-24-20 \le 4x+6x$$

$$-44 \le  10x$$

$$\frac{-22}{5} \le x$$

As the value of $x \ge \frac{-22}{5}$

$$\left[\frac{-22}{5},\infty\right)$$